# Stringのsplitクラスをつくりたい

Tags: java, string

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException、このエラーの意味はわかりますがなぜbが3回出力されaが2回出力されるのかわかりません
どなたか教えてください

```
public class KString extends Object{


    ArrayList<Character> kList = new ArrayList<Character>();

    public KString(char[] c) {
        kList.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
            kList.add(i,c[i]);
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public KString[] split(char c) {
        
        char split = c;
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < kList.size(); i++) {
            if(kList.get(i).equals(split)) {
                array.add(j,i);
                j++;
            }
        }
        int k = 0;
        char[] vc = new char[array.get(0)];
        KString[] ks = new KString[array.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < kList.size(); i++) {
            if(kList.get(i).equals(split)) {
                ks[k] = new KString(vc);
                if((i == array.get(k))) {
                    System.out.println("a");
                    vc = new char[((array.get(k+1))-(array.get(k)+1))];
                }
                k++;
            }else{
                if(k==0) {
                    vc[i-k] = kList.get(i);
                    System.out.println("b");
                }else{
                    vc[((i-1)-(array.get(k-1)))] = kList.get(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return ks;
    }
}

public class Next {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] c = new char[]{'a','b','c',',','d','e','f',',','g','h','i'};
        KString ks = new KString(c);
        ks.split(',');
    }
}
```

結果

```
b
b
b
a
a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:459)
    at ABC.KawaiString.split(KawaiString.java:57)
    at ABC.Next.main(Next.java:8)
```

Comment: どうなって欲しい(どうなるつもりで実装した)かも書いた方が良いかもしれません。(他者から見ると、なるべくしてそうなっているようにしか見えないので、本当に知りたいことと回答に齟齬が発生するかもしれません)

Answer (score 0):

1. 1~3番目の文字('a','b','c')はsplitと不一致で、かつk=0の為(k++を通る事が無い)
   bが3回出力されます。
2. 4番目(',')は一致するので、aが出力されます。
   (i == array.get(k)は、必ずtrueになると思います)
3. 5~7番目('d','e','f')は不一致の為、elseに入りますが
   k==0ではない為、何も出力されません。
4. 8番目(',')は一致のため、aが出力されますが
   その後のarray.get(k+1)で例外に落ちます

分かりやすいよう、ログを追加してみました
("c"が上記「3.」に該当するパターンです)

```java
    public KString[] split(char c) {
        
        char split = c;
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < kList.size(); i++) {
            if(kList.get(i).equals(split)) {
                array.add(j,i);
                j++;
            }
        }
        int k = 0;
        char[] vc = new char[array.get(0)];
        KString[] ks = new KString[array.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < kList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Cur Char:"+kList.get(i).toString());//add
            if(kList.get(i).equals(split)) {
                ks[k] = new KString(vc);
                if((i == array.get(k))) {
                    System.out.println("a");
                    vc = new char[((array.get(k+1))-(array.get(k)+1))];
                }
                k++;
            }else{
                if(k==0) {
                    vc[i-k] = kList.get(i);
                    System.out.println("b");
                }else{
                    vc[((i-1)-(array.get(k-1)))] = kList.get(i);
                    System.out.println("c");//add
                }
            }
        }
        return ks;
    }
```

結果は以下になります

```
Cur Char:a
b
Cur Char:b
b
Cur Char:c
b
Cur Char:,
a
Cur Char:d
c
Cur Char:e
c
Cur Char:f
c
Cur Char:,
a
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at KString.split(prog.java:36)
    at prog.main(prog.java:58)
```